# Nearby Messages API for iOS - messages do not reach the iphone

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm having problems with the service: Nearby Messages API.
I made the project according to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-started
I used library https://cocoapods.org/pods/NearbyMessages in version 1.1.1.
Everything worked fine until the previous week when iOS phones stopped getting broadcast messages from nearby api.
Code responsible for the nearby api layer was not changed.

I present logs from the `NearbyMessages-1.1.1` library:

```
2020-12-23 15:34:38.330220+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: Success
2020-12-23 15:34:38.330582+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: 0 directive(s), 3 token(s), 0 message(s), 0 publication results(s), 0 unpublish results(s), 0 subscription results(s), 0 unsubscribe results(s)
2020-12-23 15:34:38.334692+0100 Client[375:11734] Tokens: 3 good, 0 bad, 0 broadcast
2020-12-23 15:34:38.334985+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC request: 3 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 3 directive(s)
2020-12-23 15:34:38.943624+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: Success
2020-12-23 15:34:38.943897+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: 0 directive(s), 3 token(s), 0 message(s), 0 publication results(s), 0 unpublish results(s), 0 subscription results(s), 0 unsubscribe results(s)
2020-12-23 15:34:43.831088+0100 Client[375:11734] Tokens: 3 good, 0 bad, 0 broadcast
2020-12-23 15:34:43.831899+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC request: 3 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 3 directive(s)
2020-12-23 15:34:44.472385+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: Success
2020-12-23 15:34:44.472755+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: 0 directive(s), 3 token(s), 0 message(s), 0 publication results(s), 0 unpublish results(s), 0 subscription results(s), 0 unsubscribe results(s)
```

As you can see the library notices the presence of a second phone, however, the MessageFoundHandler is not notified. What could be causing this behaviour?

Can I count on your help in solving this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic here. Programming questions should be asked on [so].

Comment: in my humble opinion, the problem is on the Nearby service side not a program. As if the service has stopped working properly.

Comment: In either case it doesn't belong here.